# What's the word for a flashback or a rush of memories triggered by something?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm thinking in the context of school, like flipping through your old notebooks and just having all the knowledge flood back to you.

It's sort of like nostalgia, but more in the camp of knowledge than experiences. I've found [memory boner](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Memory+boner), but that's not quite what I'm after. Is anyone familiar with a word or a description for what I've described?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Open the floodgates of memory*?

Comment: 'Madeleine' is a trigger for a flood of memories.

Comment: Do mean a flood of facts, like from a textbook? Also given your suggestion, I guess you don't care how vulgar it is.

Comment: It's called a "flashback" or a "rush of memories".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Involuntary memory***, as defined by [Wikipedia, Involuntary Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involuntary_memory)

The most famous literary example is from Marcel Proust, *Remembrance of Things Past*.

> [Proust] describes an incident where he was eating tea soaked cake,
>   and a childhood memory of eating tea soaked cake with his aunt was
>   "revealed" to him. From this memory, he then proceeded to be reminded
>   of the childhood home he was in, and even the town itself.

This is the incident of the [madeleine](http://www.fisheaters.com/proust.html).

A technical definition of *involuntary memory*, from the first source, above, is:

> Involuntary memory, also known as involuntary explicit memory,
>   involuntary conscious memory, involuntary aware memory, and most
>   commonly, involuntary autobiographical memory, is a subcomponent of
>   memory that occurs when cues encountered in everyday life evoke
>   recollections of the past without conscious effort. Voluntary memory,
>   its binary opposite, is characterized by a deliberate effort to recall
>   the past

Comment: I ended up using the term [madeleine moment](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/books/authors/simon-heffer-proust-madeleine-wagner/) because I like how it sounds and think it's a suitable description, although I'm a little worried it's not a well-known enough expression.

Answer (score 4):

**a flood of memories**

I know you use 'flood' in the question as a verb, but perhaps use it as a noun.
Quoting [macmillandictionary.com](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/flood_2)

> 4 [countable] **a flood of memories** or feelings is a lot of strong
>   memories or feelings that suddenly affect you
>
> *> The song brought back a flood of memories.*

Comment: He's asking for the rush.  Flood is used all the time.  So is wave and so on.

Comment: So, rather than just a wave, perhaps a **tidal wave (or tsunami) of memories**.

Answer (score 1):

- [***Take a trip down memory lane***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+trip+down+memory+lane): To reminisce over memories of past events, especially happy ones.

> *My grandmother spends more time taking trips down memory lane these days than talking about the present.*

<sub>EDIT: Oops! I've just read the "more in the camp of knowledge than experiences" part. However, I think it's a nice idiom—so it's worth considering it!</sub>

Not 100% an idiom, but also consider:

- [***Come back (to me)***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/come+back): To recur to the memory.

> *It's all coming back to me now.*

[The Free Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

What about **[reminiscence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reminiscence)**:

- the act or process of recalling past experiences, events, etc.
- a mental impression retained and revived.
- Often, reminiscences. a recollection narrated or told, e.g.
  *reminiscences of an American soldier*.
- something that recalls or suggests something else.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***total recall***?

> The ability to remember with clarity every detail of the events of one’s life or of a particular event, object, or experience [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/definition/anglais/total-recall)