# What is the word for when you can taste or smell something clearly, as if you are currently experiencing it, when it was from your childhood?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is not a *déjà vu*.  It is similar, but what is the specific word?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Requests like this require an example sentence. Furthermore questions require some basic research you have done yourself. Please have a look at the [help].

Comment: Are you looking for an English equivalent of Proust's madeleine?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the word **"synesthesia"**? From Wikipedia: "Synesthesia (also spelled synæsthesia or synaesthesia; from the Ancient Greek σύν syn, 'together', and αἴσθησις aisthēsis, 'sensation') is a neurological phenomenon in which stimulation of one sensory or cognitive pathway leads to automatic, involuntary experiences in a second sensory or cognitive pathway. People who report a lifelong history of such experiences are known as synesthetes." For more information, read the article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307998/whats-the-word-for-a-flashback-or-a-rush-of-memories-triggered-by-something/308056#308056.

Comment: Perhaps *déjà senti?*

Comment: @MarkHubbard Synesthesia is identical to what I have heard called eideticism. The stimuli can be anything sensory. The result is an uncontrolled movie of a past experience, and in severe cases, the coping techniques tend to look a lot like OCD.

Comment: Why the close votes? I've been trying to dig up information on this for 30 years? It is not available as basic reference material. Clinical descriptions are, for the most part, quite recent. Decent research is pretty thin.

Comment: Phil Sweet - "Eideticism" or eidetic memory is one of the words I was looking for as well! I knew a woman in her late 80s who said she vividly experienced sitting on the floor of her bedroom as a *very* young child with her back to the wall and sunlight from the window shining across her legs. She described the dress she was wearing, could feel how the fabric felt on her skin, the warmth of the sun, and all the details of the room. Her eideticism was my first encounter with it. I voted to re-open this question and hope that @Zim comes back to fill-out his question to make it acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

**Sensory Memory**. Smell is called [olfactory memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olfactory_memory), touch is called [haptic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_memory), hearing is called [echoic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echoic_memory), and image is called [iconic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconic_memory). Oddly, there doesn't seem to be a term for taste memory. Another term of interest is [eidetic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory). Eidetic memory (unlike the link's description) can be applied to all the senses, and it refers to the strong, sometimes overwhelming and debilitating, welling up of memories caused by some recent stimulus. I have a good friend with this condition.

Comment: @Robusto fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is the term [**involuntary memory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involuntary_memory) that is the *memory that occurs when cues encountered in everyday life evoke recollections of the past without conscious effort.*

This is most notably described by Marcel Proust in his novel [*Remembrance of Things Past*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Search_of_Lost_Time).  Notably, he describes an incident where the taste of a madeleine cake dipped in tea brings forth memories of his youth.

However, this specific scenario (though not necessarily the entire range of *involuntary memory*) occurs when a taste (in this case) brings back other memories, vs something bringing back the memory of a taste/smell.